# Protect Returns & Warranty Requests from other users in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, account

Is there any way to protect [**WooCommerce Returns & Warranty Requests**](https://woocommerce.com/products/warranty-requests/) plugin's request/status page (the slug of the page I created is "returns") from users that the order number or warranty request number doesn't belong too?

In default mode the page is open to public, hence, even if a visitor visits this url **.../my-account/returns/?order=35** can see the all warranty request details that the original user requested, is there any way to protect this page? I want to use a code that checks if user is not logged in and if the order number or warranty request number doesn't belong to the logged in user then don't show the /returns/ page.

I was able to use this code in my functions.php to prevent not logged in users to see the /returns/ page:

```
function template_redirect_returns()
{
    if( is_page(returns) && !is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        $loginUrl = home_url('/my-account/orders/');
        wp_redirect($loginUrl);
         exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect_returns' );
```

But how can I also prevent the users from seeing the page if the **?order=35** doesn't belong to them?

I asked the plugin developers and also reported many bugs but they don't care to fix the issues.

I will appreciate your help! With gratitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `is_page(returns)` should be replaced by `is_page('returns')` as it throws an error.

Try the following (untested):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect_returns' );
function template_redirect_returns()
{
    if( is_page('returns') ) { 
        if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url('/my-account/') ); //  instead of '/my-account/orders/'
             exit();
        }
        // For logged in users
        else {
            // Testing if current user ID match with order customer ID
            if( isset($_GET['order']) && get_post_meta( $_GET['order'], '_customer_user', true ) != get_current_user_id() ){
                wp_redirect( home_url('/my-account/orders/') );
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> This is a real security bug in this plugin, and **should be notified to authors**.

Comment: Thank you dear for your fast response and for your effort to help resolve this bug. I tried your provided code and it is working but if we use **is_page** insted of **is_wc_endpoint_url**

Comment: @tatifox Thanks I have updated the code placing back `is_page()`…